# Auto-incremento ORACLE/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, contador, cursor

```
Nome    Idade   ID
João    5       
Lucas   5   
João    2   
Lucas   1
```

Gostaria de utilizar um cursor para ordenar por nomes e por idade e que o campo ID fosse populado conforme a sequencia, exemplo:

```
Nome    Idade   ID
João    2       1
João    5       2
Lucas   1       1
Lucas   5       2
```

É Possível?

Comment: pode informar o cenário? Essas informações estão sendo inseridas? estão em um select? Não ficou claro sua duvida...

Comment: Essas informações estão presente em uma tabela. oque seria inserido só o ID

Comment: Declare
  v_contador  number := 0;
  v_min_idade number := 0;
  cursor c_i is
    select t.*, rowid from teste_matheus t order by nome, idade asc;
begin
  for i in c_i loop    
    select min(idade)
      into v_min_idade
      from teste_matheus
     where id is null
       and nome = i.nome;       
    if i.idade = v_min_idade and i.id is null then
      v_contador := v_contador + 1;
            update teste_matheus t
         set id = v_contador
       WHERE id is null
         and t.nome = i.nome;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;

Assim, está trazendo ID iguais por nome.

Answer (score -1):

A função dense_rank atribui um ranking aos valores selecionados. No caso do código abaixo, para cada Nome, aplica um ranking de acordo com a Idade, e salva este ranking no campo ID.

```
SELECT Nome, Idade, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Nome ORDER BY Idade) AS ID FROM $a$
```

Comment: Evite colocar código sem explicação. Relembro que o que é claro para si pode não ser para um leitor que se depare com a pergunta, e dessa forma, pode não conseguir acompanhar o seu raciocínio.

Comment: Obrigada, Isac! Editei minha resposta.